# I need to change a variable in the parent from the child in actionscript 3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, variables, parent-child

I am new at actionscript 3. I want to change a variable set to 0 in the parent to 1 when a button in the child is clicked.

**This is the parent zero.swf:**

```
var noPass:Number=0;

function getPass(event:onLoad, noPass):void {
    if(noPass==0) {
        var passRequest:URLRequest=new URLRequest("PasswordPage.swf");
        var passLoader:Loader = new Loader();
        passLoader.load(passRequest);
        addChild(passLoader);
    } else {
        removeChild(passLoader);
        var navRequest:URLRequest=new URLRequest("nav/ILNav.swf");
        var navLoader:Loader = new Loader();
        navLoader.load(navRequest);
        addChild(navLoader);
    }
}

addEventListener(onLoad, getPass, noPass)
```

**this is the child PasswordPage.swf:**

```
submit_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, subClick, noPass);

var myName:String;
var myPass:String;

function subClick(event:MouseEvent, noPass):void {

    myName=name_txt.text;
    myPass=pass_txt.text;
    failedName_txt.text="";
    failedPass_txt.text="";

    if (myName=="Kim"&&myPass=="Pablo") {
        //this.parent.removeChild(this);
        //DisplayObjectContainer(this.parent).removeChild(this);
        //unload(passLoader);
        noPass=1


    } else if (myName != "Kim") {
        failedName_txt.text="You have entered the wrong Username.";
    } else {
        failedPass_txt.text="You have entered the wrong Password.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Nevermind I have given up on that.

Answer (score 0):

You could always add your mouse event listeners to the child's button from within the parent swf. For example, in the parent clip you could do something like this:

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, _configureChild, false, 0, true);
loader.load(new URLRequest("PasswordPage.swf"));

function _configureChild(e:Event):void {
   var info:LoaderInfo = e.target as LoaderInfo;
   var mov:MovieClip = info.loader.content as MovieClip;
   var btn:MovieClip = mov.getChildByName("submit_btn") as MovieClip; 
   submit_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, _childClickHandle, false, 0, true);

}

function _childClickHandle(e:MouseEvent):void {
   /// blah blah blah
}
```